# Visual Studio doesn't detect .net4 on win8

Tags: windows-8, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I've a very messy problem! I have installed VS 2013 on my win 7 PC and i'm happy with it!
but i can't use my projects on win 8 because VS doesn't detect .Net 4, e.i. when i open my projects i get an error:

[image: error]

Also i can't create new projects with .Net 4:

[image: frameworks]

I googled around and see some solutions, like dealing with "Turn Windows features on and off",
but none of them helped me.

What should i do?

p.s. 1: I know .NET 4 is installed.

p.s. 2: I HAVE TO use .NET 4, because server admin hasn't upgrade framework!

Comment: You don't have .NET 4.0 installed, it was overwritten by 4.5.1.  What it is complaining about is that your machine is missing the targeting pack for 4.0.  That's unusual and something the worry about, the installer didn't do the complete job.  There might be more stuff missing.  You can at least follow its recommendation and select the 2nd bullet.

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual Studio solution, right-click the project and go into properties. Go to target Framework drop down and select 4.0.

Make sure you have this set for either Debug or Release (whichever you are running under).

If this doesn't work, you may need to re-install the framework, which will run fine alongside 4.5.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Also, it may help to delete the .suo file in the folder of your project in case it has become corrupt. It will be recreated the next time you run VS.

Then open visual studio as administrator and the .suo file will be recreated.

Comment: please note i CAN'T open project so i can't go into project/properties! but there is an option: i can choose first option from the form you see in the first image above, it will open the project, but there is no option for .net 4 in project/properties!

Comment: Also i can't install .net 4, because i get an error that says it's already installed. as i said before, .net 4 is installed. actually, .net 4.5 is an update for .net 4 and it contains .net 4.

Comment: I would try to reinstall Visual Studio, run the service packs and repair 4.5 framework install.